# MVC 5 View from base controller (controller inheritance)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

does anyone know how tell the child controller to load base (parent) controller view  instead of looking for it in it's own folder?

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public virtual ActionResult Test()
        {
            return View("Test");
       }
    }

    public class ChildController:BaseController
{
        public override ActionResult Test()
    {
        return base.Test();
    }
```

**And the Error is  The  view 'Test' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Child/Test.cshtml.....**

So the solution that I found yeat is to make parent action looks like this

```
public class BaseController : Controller
        {
            public virtual ActionResult Test()
            {
                return View("~Views/Base/Test.cshtml");
           }
        }
```

Is there any better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private const string ViewPath = "~/Views/{0}/{1}.cshtml";
private ViewResult GetView(string action, object model = null)
    {
        var controllerName = ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();

        var path = string.Format(ViewPath, controllerName, action);

        return
            new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = path
            };
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks